# Clearing array and label on a form

Tags: visual-studio

I'm writing a simple program in Visual basic.net that sorts names. Clicking the "report" button on my form sorts an array of names and displays it in a label on the form. Clicking the "reset" button clears all fields and the array and starts over. My problem is that when I reset, the next list of names displays halfway down on the label. How can i fix this?

```
Public Class Form1

    Const MaxArray As Integer = 29
    Dim NameArray(MaxArray) As String
    Dim NameCounter As Integer = 1
    Dim ArrayCounter As Integer = 0

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load    
        SetDefaults()
        Reset()     
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddButton.Click
        'This button adds each name into the array by clicking the "add" button.
        'erases the First and Last name fields.
        'Adds number to entry counter.

        FillArray()     
        DisplayEntry()
        ClearFields()   
        NameCounter = NameCounter + 1   
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReportButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ReportButton.Click
        'the report button displays the names on the label

        Try
            SortArray()
            DisplayArray()
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorLabel.Text = ex.Message
        End Try

        ErrorLabel.Text = "Report Created." 
    End Sub 

    Private Sub ResetAllButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ResetAllButton.Click
        'This button clears the array, all fields and labels, and starts over
        SetDefaults()
        SortArray()
        DisplayArray()

        ErrorLabel.Text = "Reset Complete." 
    End Sub

    Sub ClearFields()
        'This sub clears only the first and last name fields.
        FirstNameBox.Text = String.Empty
        LastNameBox.Text = String.Empty
    End Sub

    Sub FillArray()
        Try
            NameArray(ArrayCounter) = LastNameBox.Text & "," & FirstNameBox.Text

            ArrayCounter += 1

        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorLabel.Text = ex.Message
        End Try 
    End Sub

    Sub SortArray() 
        Dim TempVar As String
        Dim ChangeHappened As Boolean = False

        Try
            Do
                ChangeHappened = False

                For LoopCounter As Integer = 0 To ArrayCounter - 1
                    Select Case True
                        Case (LoopCounter + 1) > ArrayCounter - 1

                        Case NameArray(LoopCounter) > NameArray(LoopCounter + 1)

                            TempVar = NameArray(LoopCounter)
                            NameArray(LoopCounter) = NameArray(LoopCounter + 1)
                            NameArray(LoopCounter + 1) = (TempVar)


                            ChangeHappened = True

                        Case Else

                    End Select
                Next    
            Loop While ChangeHappened = True    
        Catch ex As Exception
            ErrorLabel.Text = ex.Message
        End Try

        ErrorLabel.Text = "Done."
    End Sub

    Sub DisplayArray()  
        For LoopCounter = 0 To ArrayCounter - 1
            SortedNameLabel.Text = SortedNameLabel.Text & NameArray(LoopCounter) & Environment.NewLine
        Next    
    End Sub

    Sub DisplayEntry()  
        UnsortedNameLabel.Text = UnsortedNameLabel.Text & LastNameBox.Text & "," & " " & FirstNameBox.Text & Environment.NewLine

        EntryCounterLabel.Text = NameCounter.ToString   
    End Sub

    Sub SetDefaults()   
        NameCounter = 1
        SortedNameLabel.Text = String.Empty
        UnsortedNameLabel.Text = String.Empty
        FirstNameBox.Text = String.Empty
        LastNameBox.Text = String.Empty

        Array.Clear(NameArray, 0, NameArray.Length)

        For LoopCounter = 0 To ArrayCounter - 1
            SortedNameLabel.Text = SortedNameLabel.Text & NameArray(LoopCounter) & Environment.NewLine
        Next    
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Please reformat the code.

Answer (score 0):

In `SetDefaults()`, you're adding a bunch of blank lines to the Label.  Additionally, you're not resetting ArrayCounter to zero.

With that in mind, try changing it to:

```
Sub SetDefaults()   
    ArrayCounter = 0
    NameCounter = 1
    SortedNameLabel.Text = String.Empty
    UnsortedNameLabel.Text = String.Empty
    FirstNameBox.Text = String.Empty
    LastNameBox.Text = String.Empty

    Array.Clear(NameArray, 0, NameArray.Length)
End Sub
```